# Node receive post json from axios post

Tags: node.js, json, express, post, axios

I have 2 different url, the first one receive a form action from an html page with the data and make a post request to the second url. This receive the json and with express make a get request with this json.

How can I read a json that I receive from another url with post request made with axios?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Axios response returns an object containing `data`;

```
const {data: json} = await axios.post(/*details*/);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: thanks, but how I read this json on the second url? sorry but i'm new in all this

Comment: JSON will be valid javascript object, structured in the form of key, value.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand, how can I read from the second url(where I receive the json) the json that I sent? Just with console.log(json)?